# Within a radio-group how does one target via (a) css-selector(s) unchecked controls while there is also a checked/focused control amongst the group?

Tags: css-selectors, radio-button, radio-group, pseudo-class, checked

Is it possible within a radio-group to change the style of a radio button that has not been checked after the other button has been checked?

I have 5 radio boxes. I gave a custom style to the checked ones with the `:checked` pseudo class. But when a control is checked I want the others to be less visible. I used the negation `:not(:checked)`, but in case none of the controls is checked, all of them are less visible. I just want the unchecked controls of a radio-group to be less visible after another control of this group has been checked.

How can I do this with javascript or css?

Comment: You can view my work here: **https://codepen.io/Screwy791/pen/zYaZvQR?editors=1100**

Comment: The codepen markup is invalid; a `<div/>` element is not a valid child of a `<label/>` element. Also `<div/>` tag-soups do not provide any semantic structure/information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OP might make use of the [`:focus-within`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-within) css pseudo class like demonstrated with the below provided example.

```css
/*
fieldset:focus-within span {
  opacity: .3;
}
fieldset:focus-within [type="radio"]:focus + span {
  opacity: 1;
}
*/
fieldset:focus-within [type="radio"]:not(:checked) + span {
  opacity: .3;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>1st radio group</legend>

    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="foo-bar"/>
      <span>Foo</span>
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="foo-bar" checked/>
      <span>Bar</span>
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="foo-bar"/>
      <span>Baz</span>
    </label>
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset>
    <legend>2nd radio group</legend>

    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="bizz-buzz"/>
      <span>Bizz</span>
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="bizz-buzz"/>
      <span>Booz</span>
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="bizz-buzz"  checked/>
      <span>Buzz</span>
    </label>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

The next provided example applies fixes and improvements (e.g. tab navigable, valid markup, no empty / or unnecessary decorating span elements) to the OP's codepen code.

```css
body { zoom: .9; }
fieldset { margin: 0 0 5px 0; padding: 0; border: none; }

.insurance-container [type="radio"] {
  /*
    do not apply ... display: none; ...
    for it will prevent tab navigation.
  */
  position: absolute;
  left: -40px;
}
.insurance-container label {
  position: relative;
}
.insurance-container .insurance-item {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #e9e9e9;
  padding: 6px;
}
.insurance-container .insurance-item::after {
  /*
    - do not rely on empty elements for visually
      drawing a replacement of a form-control.
    - use one of the pseudo elements like `::after`
      or `::before` for such purpose.    
  */
  content: "";
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  background-color: #dddddd;
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: 500ms all;
  -webkit-transition: 500ms all;
  -moz-transition: 500ms all;
  -ms-transition: 500ms all;
  -o-transition: 500ms all;
}
.insurance-container [type="radio"]:checked + .insurance-item::after {
  border-color: #0078d6;
  border-width: 8px;
}

.insurance-container [type="radio"]:checked + .insurance-item {
  border: 1px solid #0078d6;
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
}
.insurance-container:focus-within [type="radio"]:not(:checked) + .insurance-item {
  /* make use of the `:focus-within` pseudo class */
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<fieldset class="insurance-container">
  <legend>first radio group</legend>

  <label>
    <input type="radio" value="insurance-1" name="first-group"/>

    <span class="insurance-item">
      <span class="wb-type-heading-xs">Input Title</span>
      <span class="wb-type-price">Number Value</span>
      <span class="wb-type-price">Custom Text</span>
    </span>
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" value="insurance-1" name="first-group"/>
    <span class="insurance-item">
      <span class="wb-type-heading-xs">Input Title</span>
      <span class="wb-type-price">Number Value</span>
      <span class="wb-type-price">Custom Text</span>
    </span>
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" value="insurance-1" name="first-group"/>
    <span class="insurance-item">
      <span class="wb-type-heading-xs">Input Title</span>
      <span class="wb-type-price">Number Value</span>
      <span class="wb-type-price">Custom Text</span>
    </span>
  </label>
</fieldset>

<fieldset class="insurance-container">
  <legend>second radio group</legend>

  <label>
    <input type="radio" value="insurance-2" name="second-group"/>

    <span class="insurance-item">
      <span class="wb-type-heading-xs">Input Title</span>
      <span class="wb-type-price">Number Value</span>
      <span class="wb-type-price">Custom Text</span>
    </span>
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" value="insurance-2" name="second-group"/>
    <span class="insurance-item">
      <span class="wb-type-heading-xs">Input Title</span>
      <span class="wb-type-price">Number Value</span>
      <span class="wb-type-price">Custom Text</span>
    </span>
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" value="insurance-2" name="second-group"/>
    <span class="insurance-item">
      <span class="wb-type-heading-xs">Input Title</span>
      <span class="wb-type-price">Number Value</span>
      <span class="wb-type-price">Custom Text</span>
    </span>
  </label>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. There is just one problem. Whatever box I click, the page jumps up. How do we prevent this?

Comment: @ResulOZYURT ... I updated my answer. Since each radio control was positioned absolute and with negative offsets one needs to contain the resulting effect by positioning the parent element relative(ly). I changed the settings accordingly and also made the radio-group's content longer than the code-snippet's viewport in order to demonstrate the patched jumping behavior.